# apache module to perform search and replace operations on response bodies?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, transparent-proxy

I am trying to do search and replace operation on response bodies using a transparent apache reverse proxy configuration, the below config using "mod_substitute" and "mod_proxy" works as expected :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www

        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Deny from all
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / http://thedomain.ineed.proxied/ 
        ProxyPassReverse / http://thedomain.ineed.proxied/ 

        # Set location
        <location />

           SetOutputFilter INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE
           Substitute "s|<script src=\"http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>| |niq"
        </location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the problem is I need to remove a lot of garbage from the upstream proxied server response body and mod_substitute only provides line-by-line processing which is neither efficient not practical. Any alternative modules or methods to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was easily implementable using nginx and this module - https://github.com/agentzh/replace-filter-nginx-module